# How does a backend-frontend relationship work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, frontend, backend

I could not find anywhere the relationship between a backend a frontend. Would a backend work like so?

I do not know how to explain this so I will give a scenario of using a backend theoretically and please tell me if this is how a backend works.

User logs in a website.tld/login which sends an API request to api.website.tld/login with parameters Username and Password set to what the user said. The backend will return an API key or an error message. If this API key is returned, it is put in local storage of the users browser which will be used later on to preform tasks., such as writing to a database. This api.website.tld endpoint could also be used for other developing on the platform.

I'm not sure if this is correct.

I did not try anything to solve this except many google searches! I will be developing with node.js backend and react.js frontend.

Comment: The front end is a client (could be a browser, native app, IoT device, whatever). A back end is anything the front end talks to. **What** the back end does is arbitrary; the scenario you describe is one of them. Basically any tutorial/book/etc that has a client talking to a server is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to give you general overview, main api subdomain in your example would be api.website.tld.
On this subdomain, you can have different api endpoints on different routes. For example:

```
/login
/cart
/item
```

On each of these route you would have some unique business logic.
Otherwise you are pretty on point, you would run api request to /login which will return api key. Now this api key can come in many forms. It could be jwt token. Also once this key is returned it can be saved either in local storage or as cookie.
Also apart from jwt token, server could just directly set api key in cookies.(Research stateless vs stateful servers to see the difference between the two).
Hope this answers your question